# Ace Editor Javascript: How to disable all extra commands that aren't default in textarea?

Tags: javascript, events, editor, textarea, ace-editor

I want to use Ace Editor for event handling purposes, but do not want the extra functionality and commands (toggle lines, multiple cursors, etc.), but only the default commands. Is there a  quick way to do this?

My current approach is to create an array of the standardCommands in a textarea (not sure yet how to do that) and then to remove them from all commands like this:

```
//Returns the set difference of this array and arr array
Array.prototype.diff = function(arr) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return arr.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

//Removes all Ace Editor commands which are not in the standardCommands array
function removeSpecialCommands(editor) {
    var commands = Object.keys(editor.commands.commands); //gets all commands
    var specialCommands = commands.diff(standardCommands); //gets extra ace cmnds
    editor.commands.removeCommands(specialCommands); //removes those commands
}
```

However going through every command is not easy as many can't be called directly on the editor. So I'm not sure which commands are the standard ones. Is there a simpler way to get just the standard textarea commands (tab, insert, delete, movecursor with home, pgup, arrow keys, etc.)?

Comment: Could you please describe in a little more detail why do you want to do this? I can't think of a reason to want to disable multiple cursors.

Comment: I want to recreate the typed code from the stored events and dealing with multiple cursors became too complicated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/24608974/1743328, if you use execCommand there won't be any problems with multiple cursors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a lot on what you consider to be a standard command. E.g. you mention `tab`, but textareas do not handle `tab`.

If your goal is to simply disable some commands that override default browser  keys you might be interested in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/keyboard/textarea.js

To also disable creating multiple selections with mouse use `editor.setOption("enableMultiselect", false)`

> going through every command is not easy as many can't be called directly on the editor

all the editor commands can be called using `editor.execCommand(commandName|commandObject)`

Comment: Incredibly good answer. Thank you very much. Might I ask, how did you acquire this information. Its not in the Ace docs and I didn't see it in the Ace commands.js file.